# Consumer keep calling poll method even when not connected to the broker

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm learning kafka with a simple consumer.
I'have configured a wrong server URL.
When using **assign** method,the clinet keep polling and prints **dddddddd** :

```
    kafkaConsumer.assign(Arrays.asList(topicPartition));
    kafkaConsumer.seekToBeginning(Arrays.asList(topicPartition));
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("xxxxxxxx");
        kafkaConsumer.poll(1000);
        System.out.println("dddddddd");
    }
```

However,when using subscribe,the poll hangs and do not move to the next instruction:

```
    kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("dddd"));
    // kafkaConsumer.seekToBeginning(Arrays.asList(topicPartition));
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("xxxxxxxx");
        kafkaConsumer.poll(1000);
        System.out.println("dddddddd");
    }
```

Why does the client keep polling when using assign/seekToBeginning?
I'm expecting the poll will hangs.

Comment: Well, it'll throw a network exception, but the while loop should still continue...

Comment: I can see that network exception when enabling debug logging.
But why it continue the loop when using assign whereas it doesn't when using subscribe?